# How to get all xml loaded tree?

Tags: magento-1.8, layout

Need to print all xml layout on frontend(index.php), because we want to check our custom xml handles were added or not.

Any one know technique to print.

Comment: Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode(); try this

Comment: Amit, i tried your code and found this code return config elements object. I am requiring xml layout. Your code return below output                          Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object ( [global] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object ( [install] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object

Comment: Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles(); try this give current page handler

Comment: Above code returns only current page handle used. output is : Array ( [0] => default [1] => STORE_default [2] => THEME_frontend_default_default [3] => catalogsearch_advanced_index [4] => customer_logged_out )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get your hands on the full xml used as layout for a page in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::generateLayoutXml`. This is the one that merges everything.
If you only need to print the xml for debug purposes from time to time, you can add this line in the method mentioned above just before the `return statement`.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->getNode();
```

or

```
echo $this->getLayout()->getXmlString(); //I recommend this one
```

If you want to build an extension, you can observe the event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` like this:

```
public function generateBlocksAfter($observer) {
    $xml = $observer->getLayout()->getXmlString();
    //do something with $xml ...print it, write it to a file....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marius, below code is working                                   echo $this->getLayout()->getXmlString();

Comment: Thanks for this answer! just my two cents though:
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getXmlString()

Comment: to print it even prettier: echo htmlentities($this->getLayout()->getXmlString());

Answer (score 4):

You can use the excellent [layoutViewer](https://github.com/astorm/LayoutViewer) created by Alan Storm for this.
Using the module, you can output the handles for a page, or all the xml for the page layout.

Check the observer Alanstormdotcom_Layoutviewer_Model_Observer in his module for some examples:

```
$layout = $this->getLayout();
$layout->getNode()->asXML()
```

and more direct, for  your want, simply output the handles used on the page:

```
private function outputHandles() {
            $update = $this->getUpdate();
            $handles = $update->getHandles();
            echo '<h1>','Handles For This Request','</h1>'."\n";
            echo '<ol>' . "\n";
            foreach($handles as $handle) {
                echo '<li>',$handle,'</li>';
            }
            echo '</ol>' . "\n";
            die();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks ProxiBlue, Your below code are working for me.               $layout = $this->getLayout();
echo $node = $layout->getNode()->asXML();

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can current handler using blow code:

```
<?php 
$Handles=Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles(); 
foreach ($Handles as $handle) : ?>
    <?php echo $handle ?>

  <?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We able to see the giant Xml tree by having

```
echo Mage::app()->getConfig()->asXml();
```

If you want to debug Layout Handles only, you can just check by this code:

```
echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->getHandles();
```

Tested : Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Source : http://ka.lpe.sh/2013/08/17/magento-debug-xml-layout-config-files/

Source : http://ka.lpe.sh/2013/08/17/magento-debug-xml-layout-config-files/

echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->asXml();